# A question on a group of order 28

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A group of order 28 with a normal Sylow 2-subgroup is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15064/a-group-of-order-28-with-a-normal-sylow-2-subgroup-is-abelian)

Let $G$ be a non abelian group of order 28. Is it true that $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order 4?

Comment: same as this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15064/a-group-of-order-28-with-a-normal-sylow-2-subgroup-is-abelian?rq=1